# Get project in Eclipse plugin without having an open editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In a Eclipse plugin it's easy to get the current project(`IProject`) if there's an editor opened, you just need to use this snippet:

```java
IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

IFileEditorInput input = (IFileEditorInput)editor.getEditorInput();
IFile file = input.getFile();
IProject project = file.getProject();
```

But, is there a way to get the project if I don't have any kind of file opened in the editor?, i.e: imagine that you have a plugin that adds an option when you right click a project, and if you click this option a dialog window is launched, how can I print the project name in this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For menu items and the like which use a 'command' with a 'handler' you can use code in the handler which is something like:

```java
public class CommandHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
  @Override
  public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
  {
    ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);

    if (sel instanceof IStructuredSelection)
     {
       Object selected = ((IStructuredSelection)sel).getFirstElement();

       IResource resource = (IResource)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(selected, IResource.class);

       if (resource != null)
        {
          IProject project = resource.getProject();
          ...
        }
     }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a really good option for that specific case, and I think I can use it but I was looking for a more general solution, one that could be used anywhere without worrying about editors or extending other classes.

Comment: I don't think there is a general solution, just a lot of specific solutions for individual cases.

Comment: I was afraid of that, anyway, the snippet you provided works fine

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "The current project"? Getting a specific project will always require some way of uniquely identifying *that specific* project.

If by *current* project you mean that the project is open, then that's not a good criterion for uniqueness (in the general case), since multiple projects can be open at the same time.

A guarantee of uniquely defining a project is by getting a reference to a resource contained by that project. For example, this can be done through the editor input, as you state, or trough a selection, as [greg pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524079/1437100).

If you have the project's name, then you can use [`IWorkspaceRoot#getProject(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getProject(java.lang.String)), but I assume that's not the case. Still, for completeness:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("MyProject");
```

You could also get a list of all projects, and iterate over that list to check for a property that you know the project has (or the projects *have*). See the example below. Of course, this again doesn't guarantee uniqueness in the general case, since there can be multiple projects that satisfy the criteria. That's why I used Lists in the example.

```java
IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
List<IProject> openProjects = new ArrayList<>();
List<IProject> myNatureProjects = new ArrayList<>();
for(IProject project : projects)
{
    if(project.isOpen())
        openProjects.add(project);
    if(project.hasNature("MyNatureId")
        myNatureProjects.add(project);
}
```